# javascript capture css rule block in string

Tags: javascript, css

How to capture css rule block in a string?
This is too hard for me to capture, without the new line

```css
.fa { color: red; }
small { font-size: 16px; }
#content { background-color: blue; }
```

What I want to accomplish is to get each those block into array

```js
['.fa { color: red; }', 'small { font-size: 16px; }', '#content { background-color: blue; }']
```

Is this possible in javascript regex?

UPDATE

Sorry guys, I Thought this is only solvable with regex,
But got an answer which is way simpler, Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by capture? Are those rules already in a multi-line string and you just want to split it into an array? Or you want to read the property values from the CSS w/ JS and then split them into an array?

Comment: Without those new line, I specifically added regex on the description so that answers will be base on regular expression :)

Comment: Right , but its not clear where your "starting point" is.  Do you want to use JS to read the style properties for those listed CSS declarations first, and then process the resulting strings with regex, or do you already have the CSS properties in string form?

Comment: Don't rely on important information being in the title, it should be in the body of the question.

Comment: Where is the CSS block? Is it a string passed to your CSS some where? Is it in a CSS file? Is it applied ot an element?

Comment: The css, was came from to a variable (string). i want to make it scope to specific element so that it will not be defined as a root css rule. which causes error on the design.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Split by a closing curly brace:

```js
const str = `.fa { color: red; }
small { font-size: 16px; }
#content { background-color: blue; }
`

const res = str.split("}").map(e => e += "}")
console.log(res)
```

Comment: Apparently, no :), I need regex to get all the occurrence

Comment: Whaaaaatttt, got a simple and direct answer. nice nice, didnt think of this

Comment: This is one of the most roundabout and bizarre ways to do a simple string operation that I have ever seen, lol.

Answer (score 1):

You can match any sequence of characters that aren't a closing curly brace (}) up to the curly brace, as many times as there are. You might want to remove the newlines first, e.g.

```js
let s = `.fa { color: red; }
small { font-size: 16px; }
#content { background-color: blue; }`;

console.log(s.match(/[^}]*}/g));
```

Of course malformed rules will cause an issue.

Answer (score 0):

```
const css = `.fa { color: red; }
             small { font-size: 16px; }
             #content { background-color: blue; }`;

 const splitCSS = css.split(/\n/g);
```

there's a much simpler way...

Comment: This is only doable if there are new lines

Comment: Right. Given the way you posed the original question, it was assumed the string was multiline since you presented it multiline, and also specifically mentioned how you don't want to capture the newline characters......